# Custom provider claims in `additionalUserInfo.profile` are not available via firebase admin?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm following [firebase/identity toolkit docs](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to-enable-application-for-saml) for a SAML identity provider. Upon successful login, the redirect result contains attributes derived from the provider:

```js
provider = new firebase.auth.SAMLAuthProvider('saml.test-provider');
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);

...

firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
  if (result.credential) {
    console.log(result.additionalUserInfo.profile)  // Custom provider claims, e.g., {"provider-foo":"bar"}
  }
}
```

From the docs, the same values are also available via

- `result.user.getIdTokenResult().idTokenResult.claims.firebase.sign_in_attributes`
- `firebase.sign_in_attributes`

These same attributes don't seem to be stored anywhere accessible in the firebase_admin SDK:

```py
from firebase_admin import auth
user = auth.get_user(uid)
print(user.custom_claims) # => None ... *provider* claims aren't here
print(user.provider_data[0]) # => has `federatedId` and some others, but still no custom provider claims
```

Is there any way to get this info in the admin SDK? Any way to tell if it's even saved by Firebase?  Do I need to capture it in firestore (and wouldn't that be risky since the user could fake claims coming from the provider?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the additional SAML attributes are only persisted in the token claims accessible via:
`result.user.getIdTokenResult().idTokenResult.claims.firebase.sign_in_attributes`

They are not stored on the user record. Identity Platform/Firebase Auth does not persist additional user info in storage for privacy reasons.

However, you can always store the claims you need on the record via the Admin SDK.
You would send the ID token to your server, verify it, parse the claims you need and set them on the user record.

Here is sample via the Node.js Admin SDK.

```
app.post('/saveUserClaims', (req, res) => {
  // Get the ID token passed.
  const idToken = req.body.idToken;
  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
    .then(function(decodedToken) {
      const uid = decodedToken.uid;
      // ...
      const samlClaims = decodedToken.firebase.sign_in_attributes;
      // You would filter the claims as there could be too many.
      // You can also save these claims in your database, etc.
      return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, samlClaims)
        .then(() => {
          res.status(200).end();
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
     // Handle error
   });
});
```

That said, in general there is no need to save these claims as they will always be available in the ID token and you can access them from your security rules or when you pass the ID token to your server for validation. This is a better way to do this as you don't run into synchronization issue where your DB is out of sync with the user's attributes.

Comment: Thanks! In my particular case, the admin endpoint is interfacing with a different system which doesn't use firebase at all and I need to provide those claims back to that system. I'll give your token persistence example a whirl.